# how to extract message data using logstash filter for this format

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I am new to filters and logstash, here is the log message format I have

```
{
    "exception":"",
    "headers {},
    "code":"",
    "method":"main",
    "level":"INFO",
    "thread":1,
    "timeInMillis":1515624209119,
    "message":"The Server for Kubernetes has started",
    "body":"",
    "class":"kubernetes.operator.Main",
    "timestamp":"01- 10 - 2018T22: 43:29.119 + 0000"
}
```

could you please help me to write logstash filter to extract data into separate filds? thank you a lot

Comment: Formatting any code/output helps visualize the question  better.

Comment: allright, so this is a record that enters your logstash filter. what is the expected output? what needs to be formated? (also, your headers field misses ": marks to make it a valid JSON)

Comment: is this ("headers {},) a typo ? incase you mean ("headers": {},) you can use the [ JSON plugin ] (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to massage the data before indexing it, you can try using the ruby filter or aggregate filter

```
filter {    
  ruby {
       code => "  
                  msg = event.get('message') + ' - additional information.'
                  map['message'] = msg

                  #you can also iterate through all the fields
                  event.to_hash.each do |key,value| 

                  end 

                 "
    }
}
```